# Minix Process Communication (IPC)

Tags: c, process, linux-kernel, minix

I am aiming at getting the last x, say 100, send messages with the rp id (running process id) and the dest. For that purpose there are the functions sys_call and min_send. The parameters of the mind_send are exactly what I try to get. How can I modify the proc.c file so that this could happen. Just simple `printf("/d\n", n)` won't work :) and furthermore they are stored in the variable `n`. Code of the functions:

```
if (function & SEND) {
        /* Function = SEND or BOTH. */
         n = mini_send(rp, src_dest, m_ptr);
        if (function == SEND || n != OK)
                return(n);      /* done, or SEND failed */
}
```

Declaration of mind_send:

```
PRIVATE int mini_send(caller_ptr, dest, m_ptr)
register struct proc *caller_ptr;       /* who is trying to send a message? */
int dest;                       /* to whom is message being sent? */
message *m_ptr;                 /* pointer to message buffer */
{
```

Any suggestions?